# Laravel 5 How to convert date related column using Carbon in select clause?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5

I am new to php and laravel and using laravel 5.2 with MariaDB 10.1.xx.

test table has index and date (yyyymmdd) columns.

I would like to convert date format from yyyymmdd to YYYYmm without using raw query in the select clause.

I tried it as following:

```
$test = DB::table('test')
->select( 'idx',Carbon::parse('date')->format('Ym') );
```

and got error as below:

```
DateTime::__construct(): Failed to parse time string (date) at position 0 (n): The timezone could not be found in the database.
```

Please let me have any idea to solve this issue using carbon not raw query.

Answer (score 1):

In your model (`Test`) add the protected field `$dates`:

```
class Test {
    //...
    protected $dates = ['created_at', 'updated_at', 'date'];
    //...
}
```

This tells Eloquent that the field `date` (and the default timestamp-fields) contains a date. `$entity->date` will now contain a `Carbon` instance for an entity of type `Test`. You can use this to format the date (`$entity->date->format('Ym');`)

You could even write an [Accessor](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent-mutators#accessors-and-mutators) to do this for you:

```
class Test {
    //...
    public function getFormattedDateAttribute() {
        return $this->attributes['date']->format('Ym');
    }
    //...
}
```

```
echo $entity->formatted_date;
```

Answer (score 0):

Other option is to use mutators in your model something like

```
public function getDateAttribute($value){
    return Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d', $value)->toDateTimeString();

}
```

You can change or work with it as you need